# Variable jquery parameter name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of PHP language files which I use to output text to the user based on the their language choice. I have passed the PHP variables to javascript successfully and they are available as `LANG` You can see it in use in the code.

Here is my question... Since the code as shown below works perfectly, why can I not change this line...

```
'No': { 'class' : ''}}
```

to

```
LANG.no: { 'class'  : ''}}
```

Basically I want to know why I can use `LANG` elsewhere in the code but not in the line shown above or in the equivalent "Yes" line.

Here is the working code:

```
$.confirm({
    'title': LANG.return_to_exhibit_lobby,
'message': "<strong>"+LANG.return_to_exhibit_lobby_confirmation+"</strong>",
'buttons': {
'Yes': { 
    'class': 'special',
    'action': function(){
        window.location.href='logout.php';
    }},
'No': { 'class' : ''}}
});
```

Comment: Why? Because the confirm code expects "No"? and it would need to look like `Lang : { no : { class... } }`

Comment: @epascarello I don't think that is true because I could change it to something absurd like `'banana'`. I just can't but a variable name... Only a string. It can be anything... doesn't have to be "No"

Comment: @epascarello I tried the code as you suggested and it outputted "LANG" instead of "No"

Answer (score 4):

What you could do instead:

```
var params = {
    'title': LANG.return_to_exhibit_lobby,
    'message': "<strong>"+LANG.return_to_exhibit_lobby_confirmation+"</strong>",
    'buttons': {
        'Yes': { 
            'class': 'special',
            'action': function(){
                window.location.href='logout.php';
             }}
};

params.buttons[LANG.No] = { 'class' : ''};

$.confirm(params);
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're in an object literal. Syntax rules are different there because you are declaring a structure, not acting on it. You could do this:

```
var data = {
    'title': LANG.return_to_exhibit_lobby,
    'message': "<strong>"+LANG.return_to_exhibit_lobby_confirmation+"</strong>",
    'buttons': {}
};
data.buttons[Lang.No] = { 'class' : ''}
$.confirm( data );
```

Comment: You need to declare `buttons` first. `params.buttons = {}` or do as I did in my edited answer

Comment: @SimonBoudrias I saw that just before you posted that I forgot to do it. I fixed it and it works now. Thanks!